# Is there any name for common sense / knowledge integrity constraints?

Tags: terminology, data-integrity

The Wikipedia page on [data integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity) lists 4 types of integrity constraints: entity integrity, referential integrity, domain integrity, and user-defined integrity.

Is there a name for integrity constraints that stem from common sense / knowledge?

---

Example :

I have one table with 6 columns containing some data about hospital admissions:

- `hospital_admission_id` (integer field)
- `patient_id` (integer field)
- `patient_date_of_birth` (date field -> I am aware that it should be in some patient table but ignore this in this example)
- `date_of_hospital_admission` (date field)
- `date_of_hospital_discharge` (date field)
- `hospital_admission_note` (text field: a relatively long text by the medical staff summarizing some data about the patient when he was admitted at the hospital)

One integrity constraint stemming from common sense / knowledge is that the patient more than one year old at the time of hospital admission (i.e. `date_of_hospital_admission - patient_date_of_birth > 1 year`), `hospital_admission_note` shouldn't say that the patient is a neonate.

Another integrity constraint from common sense / knowledge is that a patient cannot be admitted in the hospital if he already is in the hospital (i.e. some checks would have to be done around `date_of_hospital_admission` and `date_of_hospital_discharge`).

---

I feel that:

- It's not an entity integrity constraint since it's not an issue around primary keys.
- It's not a referential integrity constraint since it's not an issue around foreign keys.
- It's not a domain integrity constraint since it's not about checking whether values are in some list.
- I guess it could be qualified as a user-defined integrity constraint but I thought they might be some more precise technology to specifically designate integrity constraints stemming from common sense / knowledge and not just a specific user's preferences.

Answer (score 4):

You're going beyond the scope of referential constraints with this (good) question. What you are looking for is more to do with [Ontologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science)) and [Archetypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_archetype) than RDBMS constraints. You could also check out this page which is on "[Intelligent Databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_database)" and gives as an example, medical records.

Check out the OpenEHR (Open Electronic Health Record [here](http://www.openehr.org)) whereby the system goes beyond data storage (essentially AIUI, your question). It's a fascinating area, touching on machine learning and artifical intelligence. It is far from a trivial problem - and in particular with medical records with all sorts of different regulatory frameworks and privacy concerns. Doctors, surgeons, dentists and pharmacists have different "views" of a patient - how to tease all these out is a major issue in the field. It will come as no surprise that the OpenEHR system is one of many competing in this fascinating and challenging area.

From the OpenEHR ([what is page](http://openehr.org/what_is_openehr))

> What is openEHR?
>
> Abstract architecture image openEHR is a virtual community working on
>   interoperability and computability in e-health. Its main focus is
>   electronic patient records (EHRs) and systems.
>
> The openEHR Foundation has published a set of specifications defining
>   a health information reference model, a language for building
>   'clinical models', or archetypes, which are separate from the
>   software, and a query language. The architecture is designed to make
>   use of external health terminologies, such as SNOMED CT, LOINC and
>   ICDx. Components and systems conforming to openEHR are 'open' in terms
>   of data (they obey the published openEHR XML Schemas), models (they
>   are driven by archetypes, written in the published ADL formalism) and
>   APIs. They share the key openEHR innovation of adaptability, due to
>   the archetypes being external to the software, and significant parts
>   of the software being machine-derived from the archetypes.
>
> The essential outcome is systems and tools for computing with health
>   information at a semantic level, thus enabling true analytic functions
>   like decision support, and research querying.

Comment: And a +1 for your interesting question.